# How can I limit the surface in which Xlib graphics primitives draw?

Tags: c, xlib

I think that's what clip are used for but I can't find any example to do this.
I need to:

- Limit the region by setting a new clipmask (altering the GC)
- Draw
- Set the GC back to its previous state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `XSetClipRectangles()` referenced [here](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/GC/convenience-functions/XSetClipRectangles.html) and `XSetClipMask()` referenced [here](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/GC/convenience-functions/XSetClipMask.html)

So:

```
Display dpy; //This is your display, we'll assume it is a valid Display
GC gc; //This is your GC, we'll assume it is a valid GC
XRectangle recs[]; //This is an array containing the clipping regions you want.
int recs_n; //This is the number of rectangles in the 'recs' array.

XSetClipRectangles(dpy, gc, 0, 0, recs, recs_n, Unsorted); //Enable clipping
drawMyClippedGraphics(); //Call to whatever you want to use for drawing
XSetClipMask(dpy, gc, None); //Restore the GC
```

For further information type `man functionName` in your terminal.

Comment: You aren't restoring the GC, you're just removing the clipmask. Turns out there's no way to retrieve the clipmask of a GC with XGetGCValues(). Thanks anyway.